# Pack a text widget on the side doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, layout, tkinter

I'm kind of new to [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter). I tried to create a `Text` widget on the left side at `0,0`, but it appears in the middle, like a default `pack()`.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *


# the ui of the main window
class Ui(object):
    # the init of the client object
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.mid_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight() / 2
        self.mid_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2
        self.root.title("Journey-opening")
        self.root.geometry("600x600+{}+{}".format(self.mid_width - 300, self.mid_height - 300))
        self.root.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.cyan = "#0990CB"
        self.root["background"] = self.cyan
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.chat_box = Text(self.frame, height=30, width=50)
        self.chat_box.pack(side=LEFT)

    def open(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

wins = Ui()
wins.open()
```

I also tried with `grid` method but it did not change anything, and also created another widget because maybe it needs 2 widgets at least.

I guess its something with my frame but I follow a tutorial and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Pack a text widget on the side doesn't work"*

That is *incorrect* the line `self.chat_box.pack(side=LEFT)` *does* pack the `Text` widget to side. It's just that it is done *inside* `self.frame` which allocates *exactly* as much space needed for the widgets it encapsulates(in this case that is only the text widget) by default. So in a way, the `Text` widget is packed, not just to left, but to *all sides*.

---

In order to have `self.chat_box` on the upper left corner, you should let frame to occupy more space than needed, in this case, it can simply occupy *all space* in the x-axis inside its parent(`self.root`). In order to do that, replace:

```
self.frame.pack()
```

with:

```
self.frame.pack(fill='x') # which is the same as self.frame.pack(fill=X)
```